# Getting java.net.UnknownHostException: bucketName.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com exception while uplaoding file to S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Getting  java.net.UnknownHostException: **bucketName.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com** exception while uploading file to S3

Below is our code snippet to connect to Amazon S3 and uploading file to S3, we are getting below exception for file uploads

Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered an internal error while trying to communicate with S3, such as not being able to access the network.Error Message: Unable to execute HTTP request: **bucketName.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com**
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request:

**Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: bucketName.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com**

This exception is observed in between and gets resolved on war redeploy or sometimes gets resolved automatically, not able to find root cause ,please help.
We are using 1.12.305 AWS Java SDK.

Is it code side issue ? Is it DNS related issue ? Is it AWS related issue ?

```
public static AmazonS3 connectToAmazonS3(String accessKeyID, String secretAccessKey) {

        LOGGER.info("Connect to the amazon s3 service using the credentials");
        try {
            final BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyID, secretAccessKey);

            final AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds);
            LOGGER.info("Successfully connected to Amazon S3 service");

            return s3Client;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occured while connecting to Amazon S3 service" + e, e);
        }

        LOGGER.info("Connection not established with Amazon S3 service");
        return null;
    }



public static void uploadFileToAmazonS3(final AmazonS3 s3Client, final String bucketName, final String keyName, String cmdStr) {
        LOGGER.info("Started upload file to Amazon S3 for key: " + keyName);

        try {
            byte[] contentAsBytes = cmdStr.getBytes(EPSCommonConstants.CHARSET_UTF8);
            ByteArrayInputStream contentAsStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(contentAsBytes);

            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
            metadata.setContentLength(contentAsBytes.length);

            PutObjectRequest req = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, contentAsStream, metadata);
            s3Client.putObject(req);

        } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {

            LOGGER.error("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which " + "means your request made it "
                    + "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response" + " for some reason.", ase);

            LOGGER.error("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage() + " " + "HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode()
                    + " " + "AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode() + " " + "Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType()
                    + " " + "Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "Caught an AmazonClientException, which " + "means the client encountered "
                            + "an internal error while trying to " + "communicate with S3, "
                            + "such as not being able to access the network." + "Error Message: " + ace.getMessage(),
                    ace);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            LOGGER.error("Caught an IOException Error Message: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Was the S3 bucket created shortly before this test was run?

Comment: Nope bucket is created on 17th March 2023

Comment: See [How do I troubleshoot the UnknownHostException error in my Java application?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/route-53-fix-unknownhostexception-error)